# file separation on the basis of matching character

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
  ATOM    856  CE ALYS A 104       0.809   0.146  26.161  0.54 29.14           C
  ATOM    857  CE BLYS A 104       0.984  -0.018  26.394  0.46 31.19           C
  ATOM    858  NZ ALYS A 104       1.988   0.923  26.662  0.54 33.17           N
  ATOM    859  NZ BLYS A 104       1.708   0.302  27.659  0.46 37.61           N
  ATOM    860  OXT LYS A 104      -0.726  -6.025  27.180  1.00 26.53           O
  ATOM    862  N   LYS B 276      17.010 -16.138   9.618  1.00 41.00           N
  ATOM    863  CA  LYS B 276      16.764 -16.524  11.005  1.00 31.05           C
  ATOM    864  C   LYS B 276      16.428 -15.306  11.884  1.00 26.93           C
  ATOM    865  O   LYS B 276      16.258 -15.447  13.090  1.00 29.67           O
  ATOM    866  CB  LYS B 276      17.863 -17.347  11.617  1.00 33.62           C
```

I have the above text file and need to make two text files on the basis of differences at position 21 in line. I wrote a script which can print the required results. But if I do not know what is the character at column 21, how can I do this job. Following is the script which I tried. suppose I do not know whether line 21 is "A" and "B" or "B" and "G" or any other combination and need to separate on the basis of line 21. How can I do this?

```
  import sys

  for fn in sys.argv[1:]:
     f=open(fn,'r')

     while 1:
        line=f.readline()
        if not line: break
        if line[21:22] == 'B':
           chns = line[0:80]
           print chns
```

Comment: no not column 21. 21st character. See the text file. it is either "A" or "B"

Comment: So you can have a number of different characters in the 5th column, and you want to sort the lines based on this character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Storing the previous value of the 21st character** from the previous line, then **adding a newline for every non-match** *(which means another group of same letters)* prints the grouped lines based on its 21st character.
- Take note that it only groups lines with matching 21st character **based on the line sequence in the file**, which means **non-sorted lines will have more than one separated groups of same 21st character**.

  ***Modified file to show this case:***

  ```
  ATOM    856  CE ALYS A 104       0.809   0.146  26.161  0.54 29.14           C
  ATOM    857  CE BLYS A 104       0.984  -0.018  26.394  0.46 31.19           C
  ATOM    862  N   LYS B 276      17.010 -16.138   9.618  1.00 41.00           N
  ATOM    863  CA  LYS B 276      16.764 -16.524  11.005  1.00 31.05           C
  ATOM    864  C   LYS B 276      16.428 -15.306  11.884  1.00 26.93           C
  ATOM    865  O   LYS B 276      16.258 -15.447  13.090  1.00 29.67           O
  ATOM    866  CB  LYS B 276      17.863 -17.347  11.617  1.00 33.62           C
  ATOM    858  NZ ALYS A 104       1.988   0.923  26.662  0.54 33.17           N
  ATOM    859  NZ BLYS A 104       1.708   0.302  27.659  0.46 37.61           N
  ATOM    860  OXT LYS A 104      -0.726  -6.025  27.180  1.00 26.53           O
  ```

  ***Code producing this case (without sorting the lines):***

  ```
  import sys

  for fn in sys.argv[1:]:

      with open(fn,'r') as file:
          prev = 0
          for line in file:
              line = line.strip()
              if line[21:22] != prev:
                  # new line separator for each group
                  print ''
              print line
              prev = line[21:22]
  ```

  ***A sample output showing this case:***

  ```
  ATOM    856  CE ALYS A 104       0.809   0.146  26.161  0.54 29.14           C
  ATOM    857  CE BLYS A 104       0.984  -0.018  26.394  0.46 31.19           C

  ATOM    862  N   LYS B 276      17.010 -16.138   9.618  1.00 41.00           N
  ATOM    863  CA  LYS B 276      16.764 -16.524  11.005  1.00 31.05           C
  ATOM    864  C   LYS B 276      16.428 -15.306  11.884  1.00 26.93           C
  ATOM    865  O   LYS B 276      16.258 -15.447  13.090  1.00 29.67           O
  ATOM    866  CB  LYS B 276      17.863 -17.347  11.617  1.00 33.62           C

  ATOM    858  NZ ALYS A 104       1.988   0.923  26.662  0.54 33.17           N
  ATOM    859  NZ BLYS A 104       1.708   0.302  27.659  0.46 37.61           N
  ATOM    860  OXT LYS A 104      -0.726  -6.025  27.180  1.00 26.53           O
  ```
- So, if you want **only one group for each same 21st character**, putting all the lines in a `list` and **sorting** it using `list.sort()` will do.

  ***Code (sorting the lines first before grouping):***

  ```
  import sys

  for fn in sys.argv[1:]:

      with open(fn,'r') as file:

          lines = file.readlines()

          # creates a list or pairs (21st char, line) within a list
          lines = [ [line[21:22], line.strip() ] for line in lines ]

          # sorts lines based on key (21st char)
          lines.sort()

          # brings back list of lines to its original state, 
          # but the order is not reverted since it is already sorted
          lines = [ line[1] for line in lines ]

          prev = 0
          for line in lines:
              if line[21:22] != prev:
                  # new line separator for each group
                  print ''
              print line
              prev = line[21:22]
  ```

  ***Outputs to:***

  ```
  ATOM    856  CE ALYS A 104       0.809   0.146  26.161  0.54 29.14           C
  ATOM    857  CE BLYS A 104       0.984  -0.018  26.394  0.46 31.19           C
  ATOM    858  NZ ALYS A 104       1.988   0.923  26.662  0.54 33.17           N
  ATOM    859  NZ BLYS A 104       1.708   0.302  27.659  0.46 37.61           N
  ATOM    860  OXT LYS A 104      -0.726  -6.025  27.180  1.00 26.53           O

  ATOM    862  N   LYS B 276      17.010 -16.138   9.618  1.00 41.00           N
  ATOM    863  CA  LYS B 276      16.764 -16.524  11.005  1.00 31.05           C
  ATOM    864  C   LYS B 276      16.428 -15.306  11.884  1.00 26.93           C
  ATOM    865  O   LYS B 276      16.258 -15.447  13.090  1.00 29.67           O
  ATOM    866  CB  LYS B 276      17.863 -17.347  11.617  1.00 33.62           C
  ```

**Edit:**

Writing grouped lines in different files do not actually need checking the previous line's value because changing the filename based on 21st character opens a new file, thus separating lines. But here, I used `prev` so that any previously created file with the same filename won't just be appended that may cause clutter or inconsistency on the file's contents.

```
import sys

for fn in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(fn,'r') as file:

        lines = file.readlines()

        # creates a list or pairs (21st char, line) within a list
        lines = [ [line[21:22], line ] for line in lines ]

        # sorts lines based on key (21st char)
        lines.sort()

        # brings back list of lines to its original state, 
        # but the order is not reverted since it is already sorted
        lines = [ line[1] for line in lines ]

        filename = 'file'
        prev = 0
        for line in lines:
            if line[21:22] != prev:
                # creates a new file
                file = open(filename + line[21:22] + '.txt', 'w')
            else:
                # appends to the file
                file = open(filename + line[21:22] + '.txt', 'a')

            file.write(line)
            prev = line[21:22]
```

The file writing part can be simplified if appending previously created files is not a problem. But, it risks writing to a file with same filename that is not created by the script or created by the script during earlier executions/sessions.

```
filename = 'file'
for line in lines:
    file = open(filename + line[21:22] + '.txt', 'a')
    file.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working fine. Actually I need to save these two outputs in two different files. "A" in one file and "B" in the other file.

Comment: @user2176228 No problem. Just change the line separator `print ''` to a line creating a new file for `B`. `print >> fileB, line`

Comment: sorry but changing line separator to print >> fileB, line is giving errors.

Comment: @user2176228 You need to create a file first. Btw I'll edit my answer in a few minutes to show you how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.split` and compare the 5th element (i.e the 21st character)

```
while 1:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line: 
        break

    # get character in 5th column
    ch = line.split()[4]
    if ch == 'B':
        chns = line[0:80]
        print chns
    else: # not sure what the character is
        pass # do something
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I do not know what is the character in 5th column. Actually I have a few files and each file have different character in column 5.

Comment: Add an `else` condition to your `if` block. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just initialize a value to None and look if it changes :

```
import sys

for fn in sys.argv[1:]:
    old = None
    f=open(fn,'r')

    for line in f:
        if not line: break
        if (old is None) or (line[21] == old):
           old = line[21]
           chns = line[0:80]
           print chns
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve. But the following code will sort the lines from all files by the 21st character in the dictionary `lines`.

```
import sys

lines = dict()
for fn in sys.argv[1:]:
    f = open(fn,'r')

    for line in f:
        if not line:
            break
        key = line.split()[4]
        if key not in lines.keys():
            lines[key] = list()
        lines[key].append(line)
```

You can then get all 21st characters that occurred using `lines.keys()`, and get a list() with all corresponding lines from the dictionary.